# Pass multiple objects to Backbone View in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js, coffeescript

Trying to pick up Backbone after watching Ryan Bates Railscast and I'm not sure how to pass multiple instance variables from my Rails controller and render them out in my Backbone view. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried something like:

```
respond_with({ photos: @photos, feature: @feature, only: @categories })
```

but I'm not sure how to pass them in my Backbone view.

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index      
    photo   = Five00px::Photo.new("jfvYEpvJLv06t0blEKNPuJyU3vjqQP6vnXh6KX3O")
    options = { 
      consumer_key: photo.consumer.key,
      feature: params["feature"] ? params["feature"] : "popular",
      image_size: 2 }

    @photos     = photo.photo_stream(options).photos
    @feature    = photo.stream_feature
    @categories = photo.stream_categories

    respond_with @photos
  end
end
```

Router:

```
class Five00.Routers.Photos extends Backbone.Router

  routes:
    "" : "index"

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new Five00.Collections.Photos()
    @collection.fetch()

  index: ->
    photo_view = new Five00.Views.PhotosIndex(collection: @collection)
    $("#photos").html(photo_view.render().el)
```

View:

```
class Five00.Views.PhotosIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['photos/index']

    initialize: ->
      @collection.on("sync", @render, this)

    render: ->
      $(@el).html(@template(photos: @collection))
      this
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding of how you might expect a Backbone app to work. If you think about the instance variables you've created in the index action, those are typically used as accessible objects in the view. For a Backbone app, once the view is rendered you would only have access to the data from when the view was rendered. Something like:

```
<script><%= "window.categories = JSON.parse(#{@categories.to_json});" %></script>
```

One approach would be to have your photo model include the other relationships when you make your query aka:

```
Photo.includes(:categories)
```

And to specify the way you want a photo to be serialized: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers since what you want is for the backbone collection to fetch from your browser to the resource, aka respond with JSON from the Photo#index action.

Or finally, to handle this entirely through Backbone and make three separate requests, one for each resource and assemble the relationships on the front end through models and collection classes. You can setup these relationships manually or use an extended backbone library for doing this, for ideas you might look at http://backbonerelational.org/.